# How to change the text color of a UITabbarItem and how to add a custom TabBar in an iPhone Application?

Tags: iphone, ios, uitabbarcontroller, uitabbar

I want to load a different custom `UITabBar` in an iPhone Application and how to put a custom colorful image to a `UITabBar`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try [this](http://ios-blog.co.uk/articles/tutorials/how-to-customize-the-tab-bar-using-ios-5-appearance-api/)

Comment: Thanks a lot. It was helpful but i am still searching for on how to add colorful images to the UITabBarItem. Can u please help me on this regard?

Answer (score 1):

if you like, you can change the background image of the tabbar.

Like this:

```
- (BOOL)tabBarController:(UITabBarController *)tabBarController shouldSelectViewController:(UIViewController *)viewController{
  NSUInteger index=[[tabBarController viewControllers] indexOfObject:viewController];
  switch (index) {
    case 0:{
        [_tabBar.tabBar setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"Image1.png"]];
      break;
    }
    case 1:{
        [_tabBar.tabBar setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"Image2.png"];
      break;
    }
    case 2:{
        [_tabBar.tabBar setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"Image3.png"];
      break;
    }
    default:
      break;
  }
  return YES;
}
```

Comment: U can directly set the image in our own view controllers classes in "init" methods with "self.tabBarItem.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"mycourses_tab"];" We dont need to implement the protocol methods here. But my worry is about how to add a colorful image to a UITabBarItem....

Comment: Inside the viewcontroller

UITabBarItem* tabBarItem =  [[UITabBarItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"" image:[UIImage imageNamed:@"button1.png"] tag:0];
    self.tabBarItem = tabBarItem;
    [tabBarItem release];

I put this when init the viewController but i think you can put inside viewdidappear